# Sign up activity not working and the program keeps showing the progress bar

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I am making a sign up screen.

The app runs, but when I click "Register", the progress bar shows and never ends.

This sign up activity is programmed to take the name image and name to the database of firebase and email and password to the auth.

```
package com.example.syyam.saifapplication;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;

public class RegisterActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private EditText mNameField;
    private EditText mEmailField;
    private EditText mPasswordField;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private Button mRegisterButton;
    private DatabaseReference mDatabase;
    private ProgressDialog mProgress;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);
        mAuth=FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
     mDatabase=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");

        mNameField=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.nameField);
        mEmailField=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.emailField);
        mPasswordField=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.passwordField);
        mRegisterButton=(Button) findViewById(R.id.registerBtn);

        mProgress=new ProgressDialog(this);
        mRegisterButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startRegister();
            }


        });
    }

    private void startRegister() {
        final String name=mNameField.getText().toString().trim();
        String email=mEmailField.getText().toString().trim();
        String password=mPasswordField.getText().toString().trim();

        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(name) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(email) &&      !TextUtils.isEmpty(password))
        {
            mProgress.setMessage("Registering User");
            mProgress.show();
            mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,password).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful())
                    {
                        String user_id=mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
                        DatabaseReference current_user_db =mDatabase.child(user_id);
                        current_user_db.child("name").setValue(name);
                        current_user_db.child("image").setValue("default");
                        mProgress.dismiss();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If sign in fails, your progress bar does not dismiss.

Check your return : add this code in onComplete() and build your app

```
 if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
   Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "fail",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   mProgress.dismiss();
 }
```